# How to Get the Sum (total) of a column in a query result set

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sum

Is there a way that I can get the sum of a column in my query result set by just clicking on the column (something like in Excel) so that I don't have to copy and paste the column into Excel to the see the total sum of all the values in the column?

I'm running SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the OVER clause to modify a SUM scope *in* your query. No GROUP BY needed

```
SELECT
    MyColumn, OtherColumn,
    SUM(MyColumn) OVER () AS SumTotal
FROM
    ...
```

Otherwise, SSMS isn't a calculating engine: it display query results so add it to your query...

Comment: @gbn Thanks! I just tried it and it worked. Beats having to switch over to excel and copying and pasting columns. The fact that I don't have to group by all the other columns is the best part.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `SUM` of particular column value.

```
SELECT EmployeeName, SUM(Salary)
  FROM YourTable
  GROUP BY EmployeeName
```